# Export default react-native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox

For my solution I want users to get all components from my library.

Example: `import Checkbox from 'MyLibrary';`

But for native, I'm don't want to make all the components my self. At least, not now. And that is why I want them to reference my library, so when I do change/write the component, it will automaticly update at their end.

For example, a checkbox. There is a default react-native checkbox (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/checkbox)

I would like to export this default component within my component.

I tried things like:

```
export { Checkbox as default } from 'react-native';
```

and

```
import { Checkbox } from 'react-native';

export default Checkbox;
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import { Checkbox as ReactCheckbox } from 'react-native';

const Checkbox = (...props) => <ReactCheckbox {...props} />;

export default Checkbox;
```

But that didn't work. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I made a mistake with the import, it's CheckBox not Checkbox...

Comment: I can elaborate on the error I'm getting:
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for build-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you are might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Answer (score 0):

It's CheckBox, not Checkbox, doh!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but, while I tried your code it didn't worked on mine too. But, you can do like this:

```
import { TextInput as myTextInput } from 'react-native';
```

But, while I checked this on expo app:

```
import { CheckBox as myCheckBox } from 'react-native';
```

From this what I think is react native doesn't support CheckBox on Expo app. But, if you libraries like `React Native Elements` or `Native Base`. Then you can import checkbox like this.

```
import { CheckBox as myCheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
```

Maybe this [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/BkCWHXqqZ) will help you.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to RE-EXPORT the React/Community checkbox as your component and replace it with your own component in future?

Native Checkbox component is only available in Android, so you have to use community built one from UI-Kitten/Native Base/React Native Element.

First explore and pick your UI Library and install it. Then you can import the checkbox component from the respective library and export it until you write your own component.

This will work

```js
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
export default CheckBox;
```

In case you want to wrap the component with default properties or styling then you can do something like below

```js
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function(props) {
    const yourProps = {
        checkedIcon: <Image source={require('../checked.png')} />,
        uncheckedIcon: <Image source={require('../unchecked.png')} />
    };
    return (
        <CheckBox {...yourProps} {...props} />
    );
}
```